# Night's Watch vs Army of Dead - Unshown battles

Tags: game-of-thrones, book-adaptation

How many battles occurred between the brothers of the Night's Watch and the Army of the Dead, which they did not show in HBO's Game of Thrones?

I remember there should be a battle lead by Jeor Mormount which HBO did not show.

I'm only asking for the current era after Jon Snow joined the Night's Watch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are asking about the actual battles and not skirmishes, etc. then the battle you mention ([Battle of the Fist of the First Men](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_the_Fist_of_the_First_Men)) is the only one that wasn't shown on screen.

Interestingly, the [Massacre at Hardhome](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Massacre_at_Hardhome) was shown in the TV show, while in the books the events in Hardhome are only mentioned (because no POV characters, including Jon, are there).

Comment: In season 3 episode 1, in the opening scene where they show Night's Watch brothers, they've returned after a fight with Army Of Dead. Also, When did Jeor asked Sam to send Raven in the previous season.

Comment: It's after this battle. _Battle of the Fist of the First Men_ happened between the last episode of Season 2 and the first episode of Season 3. Regarding the raven sending I'm not sure what is your question exactly.